# I can have a textbox appear near a selected cell, how do I get a second?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro which, when a cell within a defined range is selected, displays the contents of the cell to the left of it. It works well, located in the worksheet code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("H4:H283, J4:J283, L4:L283")) Is Nothing Then

Dim txbox As Shape
Dim locx As Double
Dim locy As Double
Dim txboxx As Double
Dim txboxy As Double
Dim movex As Double
Dim movey As Double
Dim comments As String

Set txbox = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Comments")

locx = ActiveCell.Left
locy = ActiveCell.Top

txboxx = txbox.Left
txboxy = txbox.Top

movex = locx - txboxx + 5
movey = locy - txboxy + 20

txbox.IncrementLeft movex
txbox.IncrementTop movey

comments = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value

txbox.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.text = comments

End If
End Sub
```

What I would like is a second text box, so that both could be displayed at a time, on a different range. I tried putting a copy of the above straight after with a different Sub name, referring to the different range and the different text box. When i do this, the second text box doesn't move or get populated.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange1(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("Q4:Q283")) Is Nothing Then

Dim txbox As Shape
Dim locx As Double
Dim locy As Double
Dim txboxx As Double
Dim txboxy As Double
Dim movex As Double
Dim movey As Double
Dim comments As String

Set txbox = ActiveSheet.Shapes("afr")

locx = ActiveCell.Left
locy = ActiveCell.Top

txboxx = txbox.Left
txboxy = txbox.Top

movex = locx - txboxx + 5
movey = locy - txboxy + 20

txbox.IncrementLeft movex
txbox.IncrementTop movey

comments = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value

txbox.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.text = comments

End If
End Sub
```

What is a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Dim c As Range
    
    Set c = Target.Cells(1) 'in case of >1 cell selected
    
    If Not Intersect(c, Me.Range("H4:H283, J4:J283, L4:L283")) Is Nothing Then
        With Me.Shapes("Comments")
            .Left = c.Left + c.Width 'for example
            .Top = c.Top
            .TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = c.Offset(0, -1).Value
        End With
    End If
    
    If Not Intersect(c, Me.Range("Q4:Q283")) Is Nothing Then
        With Me.Shapes("afr")
            .Left = c.Left + c.Width
            .Top = c.Top
            .TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = c.Offset(0, -1).Value
        End With
    End If

End Sub
```

Note it's easier not to use the "increment" methods to position the shape - just set the top and left directly, relative to the selected cell.